# Dotnetnuke user not registering

Tags: c#, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have just installed Dotnetnuke on my website. I put a login module on the home page from where user can register. When they click on register a form is shown they fill out the form and click register. It is not giving any error. The busy indicator was shown. I made the setting on verified but no email has been sent to the user to confirm and If I change the security setting to public the user is not being added in the database. What could be the problem.

Comment: Hasan are you using the default DNN skin? Do you have any 3rd party modules installed? In your browser are there any warnings of Javascript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. In webhosting you should select Framework 4.0 without integrated pipeline. It works only with framework 4 without integrated pipeline.